# how can I move android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, load

I just started to learn android application.

and I'm using github and want to manage the version with it.

for example, I made a project in PC1 and save it with github.

and then, download it and load it with PC2.

(SDK version and gradle version are different between PC1 and PC2)

but, I can't load the project with android emulator.

here is the picture that can be reason.

Could you tell me what is the problem?

[there is no Gradle information here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQnG9.png)

[I can't choose the module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9W85.png)

Comment: It's very likely you didn't push the whole project to github. Is it available for us to see?

Comment: of course, could you tell me what kind of information you need?

Comment: Update your question with your github repo link

Comment: https://github.com/mmol93/and_checkList_Project_201001.git

Comment: but, It's weird. I upload it with add . command.... isnt' it adding whole file command...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which files are you versioning on GitHub?
I mean, check if you have the following files to help Android Studio to import your project on other computer:

- build.gralde (app module);
- build.gradle (project level);
- settings.gradle;
- gradle.properties;
- and your code.

If you are having the problem and you have these files, maybe it is necessary you access your settings to Load/Unload modules and check if the app module is loaded or not.